# A resistor connected directly to the secondary of an ideal transformer can't consume any less power whatever the turns ratio

Tags: transformer

Since the resistor is connected directly to the secondary, its voltage will all the time equal to the induced emf across the secondary. In addition, since this is an ideal transformer, the input power = the output power, but the output power is the same as the power dissipated by the resistor. Therefore, no matter how one alters the turns ratio, the resistor dissipates the same power nevertheless. Is what I am saying right?

Comment: To help you understand: What happens to the output voltage, if you change the turns' ratio (assumed the input voltage is constant)?

Comment: You have got 'yes' and 'no' answers, because you haven't defined what 'same' means. The same power as that entering the transformer? Yes. The same power if the input voltage to the transformer remains constant while you alter the turns ratio? No. I would expect the usual assumption by most people to be the second case.

Comment: @Neil_UK indeed the wording of the question is a bit confusing, but I think that is just a symptom of confusion around the topic generally. However I think it is clear enough what needs to be explained. I'm inclined to be lenient, it's not an easy subject to grasp for a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The resistor indeed has the full secondary voltage across it, and consumes current according to Ohm's Law. The voltage on the primary will indeed be related to the secondary voltage by the turns ratio. The input current to the whole circuit will be determined by the value of the resistor: the lower its value, the more secondary current and therefore the more primary current (in order to preserve the ideal transformer property that the VI product of each side is equal). This means that the *effective* input impedance of the whole circuit becomes lower as the resistor value falls - this is known as a "reflected" impedance. The math is relatively easy to work through, and I leave this for you to do for yourself. (For you to work out : is the relationship linear?)

(To directly answer your question, increasing turns ratio for a fixed input voltage increases output voltage, and therefore output current and power, which in turn will increase input current.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

No you are wrong, if you alter the turns the input power can change and therefore the output power (which is indeed equal to the input power, as you noticed).

The reason for the change in input power is of course the change in input impedance that will occur if you change the turn ratio.

Answer (score 1):

> no matter how one alters the turns ratio, the resistor dissipates the same power nevertheless.

The amount of power dissipated by the resistor depends upon the voltage across the resistor, which, in turn, depends upon the turns ratio of the transformer and the voltage applied to the primary.

With an ideal transformer,

$$P_{resistor} = \frac{V_{sec}^2}{R} = \left(\frac{n_{sec}}{n_{prim}}\right)^2\left(\frac{V_{prim}^2}{R}\right)$$

This power would also be the power drawn by the (ideal) transformer primary. In an ideal transformer, the power consumed by the secondary circuit determines the power drawn by the primary, and they are equal in magnitude.

Answer (score -1):

> *A resistor connected directly to the secondary of an ideal transformer
> can't consume any less power whatever the turns ratio*

The resistor will consume all the power that is entering the primary. An **ideal transformer** can be assumed to have zero losses so, power out equals power in.

> *Since the resistor is connected directly to the secondary, it's
> voltage will all the time equal to the induced emf across the
> secondary.*

Correct. An ideal transformer can be assumed to have 100% coupling between primary and secondary hence the induced voltage is the primary voltage multiplied by the relevant turns ratio irrespective of load currents.

> *In addition, since this is an ideal transformer, the input power = the
> output power, but the output power is the same as the power dissipated
> by the resistor.*

Correct.

> *Therefore, no matter how one alters the turns' ratio, the resistor
> dissipates the same power nevertheless. Is what I am saying right?*

Correct. The resistor dissipates the same power as that entering the primary.

Comment: @Andy "The resistor dissipates the same power as that entering the primary." And altering the turns' ratio can't change the input power. The only way to change the input power is via changing the source itself, right?

Comment: @Jack if you alter the turns ratio, the voltage across the secondary resistor changes and the power must be greater or lesser hence, for a fixed value resistor on the secondary, when you change the turns ratio, the input power must also change.

Comment: Can anyone explain the 2 downvotes my answer has received?

Comment: Not my downvote but you seem to have missed OP's most likely source of confusion. You've taken a conservation of energy approach (which is obviously correct in itself) but as Neil_UK pointed out in a comment on the question OP is likely to be asking about a transformer with variable turns ratio fed with a constant primary voltage and with a constant resistance load on the secondary. In this case the power consumed will, of course, vary with the turns ratio. Your answer confirmed OP in their misunderstanding.

Answer (score -1):

I would think that a transformer have certain Technical capeabilities. VxI as per ohms law must be applied. But it will depend on harmonics, Capacitance, reactance and resistance of the primary which have an effect also on the secondary (on a direct coupled inductor) like self inductance, back e. m. f. On switch-on, which alters the power in the circuit in the transformer t. i. with a resistance and before back E. M. F. is realized a higher Wattage will be read but once back E. M. F. is reached self inductance in the primary, secondary and inductive load will use less power than with a resistor. Hence if an inverter controlled inductor drive supply is used spikes will be eradicated. (Cos phi must be as close to unity as possible)

Comment: The question refers to an ideal transformer.  This isn’t exhaustively defined but in general means that input power = output power and the voltage ratio is exactly equal to the turns ratio, and all other factors can be disregarded.